# Keras weighted embeddings layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, embedding

I'm trying to write a weighted embeddings layer in Keras, the layer takes weights matrix representing each time step in the input and output a weighted sum of all embedding vectors inside it.

I am using the embedding layer implementation from Keras GitHub repository, so I want to change the implementation of call function and replace the `gather` line with another matrix manipulation operations.

```py
def call(self, inputs):
    if K.dtype(inputs) != 'int32':
        inputs = K.cast(inputs, 'int32')

    out = K.gather(self.embeddings, inputs) # Change this

    return out
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What will be your weights for the embeddings?

Comment: @thushv89 for each time step, will be a vector of float numbers summed to 1 and each number represents the weight for each embedding vector

Comment: So how do you get those numbers into the call function. Is this defined as a trainable set of weights in the layer?

Comment: @thushv89 No, it is an input to the model, not trainable weights

Comment: Can you maybe draw a diagram of what you're trying to achieve and include that here? Because you are going to need two inputs. One to gather the required items from the embedding layer and then another as the set of weights, don't you?